# How do I create an array from a JSON data without repeating the values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, for-loop

I retrieved a JSON from an API that looks like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "SEA BUSES",
            "image": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "BEN BUSES",
            "image": null
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "CAPE BUSES",
            "image": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to create an array of the IDs in this form ids = [1,2,3]

this is my javascript:

```
companyid = response.data.response
        var ids = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < companyid.length; i++){
           ids.push(companyid[i].id)
           console.log(ids)
        }
```

but the output is not what I expected.
It shows this way:

```
[ 1 ]
[ 1, 2 ]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Any help please?

Comment: *"but the output is not what I expected"* What are you expecting? Although the code shown isn't the only way to do this, it certainly is simple, straightforward, and more importantly, it works, as the final `console.log` shows. So....?

Comment: it is the way you want it. You are printing it after pushing each element. Log it after the loop and you will see it as `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Matt it worked

Answer (score 1):

```
const json = {
  status: "success",
  response: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "SEA BUSES",
      image: null
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "BEN BUSES",
      image: null
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "CAPE BUSES",
      image: null
    }
  ]
};

console.log(json.response.map(item => item.id));
```

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear what exactly you want, but if you want to see the results once, move the print out of the loop:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < companyid.length; i++){
       ids.push(companyid[i].id)
    }   
    console.log(ids)
```

Comment: This is is silly error and has no long term value to the site. The question should be closed and deleted